# How to read files which contain gap i filenames using 'antiword'?

Tags: ms-word, file-get-contents, file-format, file-conversion, readfile

I am using 'antiword' to convert MSword document to text.
 I have a file with name "care job house keeper catering job13806.doc" and antiword cannot read this if passed in script.

```
  public function Convert($filenames) {         
    return $content = shell_exec('antiword'." ".$filenames.' -');//dash at the end to output content        
}
```

If a manually enter filename by typing antiword and pressing tab after few charters of filename it looks as below and executes perfectly.

```
$ antiword care\ job\ housekeeper\ catering\ job13806.doc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
shell_exec("antiword '$filename' -");
```

That'd produce:

```
antiword 'care job housekeeper catering job13806.doc' -
```

Comment: but I want to put this in a script. there are thousands of files....below is my script to put "\" in place of " " in between filename... but it is displaying error..
$file1=str_replace(" "," \",$file1);

Comment: don't do that. use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) instead.

Comment: Hi , actually escapeshellcmd got worked instead of escapeshellarg... but '\' is not getting before ',' in file names..
example: catering job,bar mam,customer service1924.doc - not working , but for cv done \(1\)14339.doc- working.